# mysql записать в столбец дату последнего изменения строки

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, там строчки, есть столбец, отвечающий за последнее изменения. Как сделать так, чтобы автоматически при изменении в этой строке каких либо данных, там отображалась дата последнего изменения?

Answer (score 2):

Измените **table** и поставьте на SQL

```
ALTER TABLE  `table` ADD  `last_edit` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Как это сделать через PHP?

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает.

Comment: У меня после редактирования и сохранения дата по 0000 сбивается. Может из-за самого UPDATE?

            //Корректировка
            if (isset($_POST["edit"])) {
                $query = "UPDATE carts SET series='{$_POST['series']}',num='{$_POST['num']}',date_start='{$_POST['date_start']}',date_finish='{$_POST['date_finish']}',date_last_use='{$_POST['date_last_use']}',status='{$_POST['status']}',history='{$_POST['history']}' WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                unset($row);
            }

Comment: не понял по моему все нормально

Answer (score 1):

```
 `created_at` DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: А как сделать это через PHP?

Comment: обновить схему таблицы? раскройте вопрос пжлса